# FileIOPermissionAccess and ACL in FileIOPermission

Tags: c#, .net, security, acl

One of the [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc2sxa62%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) contructors takes both a [FileIOPermissionAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  and [AccessControlActions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf9ts165%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) enums. I don't see how the second enum is useful here since the first one gives already the access restriction needed - not to mention inconsistencies.

The documentation is not clear on how the ACL information is used here. What is the value added by the ACL parameter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The control parameter specifies whether the access control list (ACL)
for the file or directory specified by path
can be changed, viewed, or cannot be accessed.
```

AccessControlActions define whether the Permissions specified in FileIOPermissionAccess can be changed, viewed or are locked.

**Change** User can change the ACL of the specified path.

**View** User can view the ACL of the specified path but cannot change the ACL any more.

**None** User can neither change nor view the ACL of the specified path.

Practically this means you can allow a user to view the contents of a folder but deny to view the ACL of this folder.